# How to determine bottleneck in slow sql query on azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have a table in a SQL database that has time data. It currently contains around 15 million rows.

When I query it to get the data between two time points on my local machine, the query executes in around 2 to 3 seconds.

When I deploy to azure and run the same query from postman, the query always times-out (more than 2 minutes).

In the monitor section on azure, I can see that DTUs go to 100% when I execute the query. But when I go to query performance insight and check the query (check image), I cannot really tell what is causing this bottleneck.

The question is: How can I determine what is causing this slowdown on azure?

[image]

**EDIT**
The table looks like this:

```
Id | TimeStamp | MachineId | Value1 | Value2 |
```

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table as r
WHERE ((r.MachineId = 3357) AND ('2020-03-30 09:00:00' <= r.TimeStamp)) AND (r.TimeStamp <= '2020-04-10 09:00:00')
```

Comment: you can't compare the performance of your local machine vs azure. There's many different aspects that can affect the performance: amount of data, latency, concurrency...You'd better inspect the execution plan and check if there's a problem with your query

Comment: The Query Store has more details, including the query plan and the query wait stats. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Im not an expert in sql so I don't know what to look for in the execution plan.

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the question to show the query.

Comment: That shouldn't be any problem. Looks like the table isn't properly indexed on `MachineId` and `TimeStamp`.

Comment: Adding to @GertArnold's comment, you'll get the best performance for this query with a clustered index on `MachineId` and `TimeStamp` since you're selecting all columns.

Comment: @DanGuzman I already have a clustered index on those columns. I think the query itself is simple, I was looking at what could be happening on azure and how to investigate it.

Comment: @psclkhoury, is the clustered index key order `MachineID` followed by `Timestamp`? How many rows are returned and how wide are the rows?

Comment: @DanGuzman I didnt know the order of the index mattered. I have IX_Table_MachineId_TimeStamp. The rows have 25 columns and the number of rows returned is high from 10k up to 250k.

Comment: Yes, key order matters unless the criterial is all equals. The equality predicate key (MachineID) needs to be for the inequality predicate (TimeStamp) to avoid touching all the machines in that date range.